# How to switch between accurate current sources

Tags: mosfet, current-source, precision

I would like to switch between two resistor loads in order to change a current source value.  The current way that I am doing it is with something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMVhTj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where M1 and M4 are low (< 10mΩ) Rds(on) MOSFETs at 8.5V Vgs.

Is there a better way to do this?  Changing Vref changes the compliance of the current source, so it would be better to change the resistor.  Unfortunately, the resistors value (the dominant error term here) is known to .1%, so M1 needs to be < .1% of R1 (or <10mΩ), and these MOSFETs are a little on the expensive side.

Comment: I assume a "real" switch wouldn't work.  ("real" as in toggle, relay, rotary or other style of mechanical switch.)

Comment: I was hoping to do this electronically.  I'm going to check some relays: though I'm a little worried about the resistance there, I'm not sure it is actually low enough.

Comment: Assuming precision resistors, can't you exclude the mosfets from your sense path? And what important criteria are you considering, regarding the opamp?

Comment: @jonk: I've thought about that, but I think I would need two fets per resistor (plus at least two driving fets).  They wouldn't need to be as low resistance though, so maybe this would work.

Comment: @jonk:  The op amp important criteria is pretty much just offset voltage (though the overall offset can be tweaked, so just the temp. coefficient), and noise.  The voltage noise shouldn't going to be too big of a problem (low µV for DC, on top of a volt is ppm, so not a concern), and the current noise is likely to be similarly unimportant (nA on top of a mA isn't a worry).  The noise in the instrument amp that is reading this is much more of an issue.  There, the noise floor of any available instrument amp is ~.5µVp-p, which sets the measurement floor of the instrument amp.

Comment: My brain is elsewhere right now and the crude design that is in my mind probably isn't worth sharing as an answer. It uses two opamps, with one (+) input to one side of a precision R and with the (+) input of the other opamp to the other side of the same R. One of the opamp outputs drives the (-) input of the other one. And there's more. It may be over-kill. I just don't have the time right now to play around with it more.

Comment: @jonk: Huh.  You have me intrigued, but I'm not sure where you are going at the moment.

Comment: I started with a high side sourcing transistor sourcing through a precision R and then into the grounded load. An opamp output drives the sourcing transistor, with its (+) input to the node shared by the precision R and the load. The output of another opamp drives its (-) input and a resistor divider (matched, but not precision), the center node of which drives the (+) input of a third opamp. The (+) input of this second opamp comes from the other side of the precision resistor, but its (-) input comes from the output of that 3rd opamp... and now you can see why I don't want to post it..

Comment: I will if you insist. But it is just brute force. Besides, I've not taken things into account and I'm not sure it will actually be useful here. Too bad I can't use the schematic editor here in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making your life unnecessarily difficult. Instead of switching both sense resistors,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcCyqj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also, you should look carefully at your MOSFET's Rds(on) rating. Usually, the rating is given at large currents. Since you are only dealing with 100 mA max, you can probably get away with a cheaper FET.

Comment: Any good recommendations for FETs?  I'm having trouble finding them (there are just so many) and they frequently only specify Rds(on) for one current in the parametric searches of Mouser and Digikey.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a purchasing recommendations site. Pick a manufacturer and start drilling down.

Comment: @AndrewSpott don't look at Rds_on for the "current" value, Rds_on is driven by the Vgs value, the current through drain-source is provided as the "output" for a certain combo of Vgs and Rds_on.

Comment: @KyranF: you can have different currents and Rds(on) with the same Vgs: see http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/302/BUK7K8R7-40E-840659.pdf for example.

Comment: Also, @WhatRoughBeast: your solution also loses out in precision.  The resistors error now increases (roughly by a factor of two...), unless I want to buy .05% resistors (which are much more expensive)

Comment: @AndrewSpott if you are referring to figure 7, i think you are reading it wrong - the Vgs value essentially controls Rds_on, and for a given Vds, you get the current values shown. If you are talking about Figure 11, then that's probably more of an issue of the physics of the electron carrying capabilities and the material bottle-necking (and increasing in resistance) at high Ids currents... The operating range you use these in probably will go nowhere near these issues though.

Comment: @AndrewSpott R1 and R2 in your diagram have essentially the same (like within 10%, that is engineering equal!) tolerance as R1 and R2 in this answer for the same current accuracy. If you think differently, then you need to understand why you think that, and work at it until you understand this comment.

Comment: @Neil_UK:  Yea, I did the math, and I was wrong, it turns out it is actually less, though that is surprising to me.